# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: APPDEFAULT

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: APPDEFAULT
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:534) [jasperreports-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2] 

    JRExporter ex = new JRPdfExporter();
    ex.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    ex.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);
    ex.exportReport(); // exception here
```

I exports HTML successfully 
but when trying to export jasper report to PDF by this code I have that exception.

I googled it I found answer is to add iText2.1.7.jar, I added it 
but still having the same exception

Comment: I know it's an old question, but i run into the same problem. Changing to itext 2.1.7 solved the problem for me. Just be sure that you have only this file in the classpath, because the PdfName.APPDEFAULT is missing from the older versions.

Answer (score -1):

You should change the version of iText.jar.put itext-4.2.0.jar in you path,OK

Answer (score -3):

Try to add `iTextAsian.jar`.

You can find `ireport` libs to `<root of ireport installation>/ireport/modules/ext`